# Git on server with no SSH access

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have copied all of the files from my production server into a local repo. I want to set up Git on the production server (Linux) so that when I push changes, they are automatically synchronized with the server.

Unfortunately, our hosting service does not allow us SSH access. Is it possible to install and set up Git on the server without having SSH access? (I can run commands in a php script using shell_exec() as kind of a workaround).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278888/private-git-repository-over-http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use http, https or git protocol instead of ssh. More information you can find [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP/S-Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some close threads with popular answers:

- **[How to make a “git push” update files on your web host?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210851/how-to-make-a-git-push-update-files-on-your-web-host)**
- **[Pushing from GitHub to a Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367247/pushing-from-github-to-a-web-server)**
- **[Private git repository over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278888/private-git-repository-over-http)**